# how to use the functcomp code in R

Tags: r

I am having trouble using the functcomp package in R. 
I have 2 datasets: one with species frequency, and the other listing the functional traits of my species. The frequency dataset has 264 species listed in the first row and 27 sites listed in the first column, all values in dataset are between 0-1. The functional trait dataset has the same 264 species (copied & pasted from the frequency dataset to make sure identical) listed in the first column, and 5 different functional traits listed in the 1st row (height, life history, life form, origin, palatability).
I am using the following code:

```
traits.df <- read.table("species_functional_traits_6_ August.txt", header = TRUE)
frequency.df <- read.table("Spring 2014 - combined table - 6 August.txt", header = TRUE)
x <- (as.matrix(traits.df))
a <- (as.matrix(frequency.df))
functcomp(x, a, CWM.type = c("dom", "all"), bin.num = height)
```

But keep getting the following error message:

> Error in functcomp(x, a, CWM.type = c("dom", "all"), bin.num = height) : 
>    Different number of species in 'x' and 'a'.

I have tried fiddling with a couple of things in the code and datasets, but cannot work out what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are links the frequency & trait data (a subset of it, but still get same error message with this data) as a tab-delimited text file

frequency: https://www.dropbox.com/s/girs3nrq1ciyg1a/frequency%20-%20small.txt?dl=0

traits: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l888sallx7mu3f6/traits%20-%20small.txt?dl=0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: I have added a link to a smaller subset of the data. please let me know if I need to add anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try stating row.names=1 when read in your table, this solved my problem - 
Anna